# Regex in a json data?

Tags: php, regex, json

I have a regex in the json data,

```
$config = '{"regex": "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"}';
```

And I want to convert the json data to an array,

```
$config = json_decode($config,true);

var_dump($config);
```

It returns `NULL` due to the regex.

How can I get around to it?

So I can get this,

```
Array
(
    [regex] => "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"
)
```

is it possible?

**edit:**

it returns,

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) '{"regex": "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"}'
}
```

should be...

```
array(1) {
  ["regex"]=>
  string(22) "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"
}
```

Comment: To get a backslash in JSON, you will need to escape it - it's no regex literal. Also, you'd need to double-escape them for your PHP string. Not sure if PHP stumples upon that…

Comment: I think you have a mistake with `span_regex` and `sregex`. Do you really want these other names, and why?

Comment: sorry my typo mistakes. i have edited it.

Comment: I help you with editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON has `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` so you are having Erros

**Option A**  You should use `stripslashes` first but you would lose backslash `\`

```
$config = '{"regex": "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"}';
$config = json_decode(stripslashes($config),true);
var_dump($config);
```

Output

```
array
  'regex' => string '/font-size:s*(?:.*);/i' (length=22)
```

**Option B** Create your own function

```
$config = '{"regex": "/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i"}';
var_dump(splitJSONObject($config));
```

Output

```
array
  'regex' => string '/font-size:\s*(?:.*);/i' (length=23)
```

Function Used (*Only Splits to array*)

```
function splitJSONObject($json) {
    $json = str_replace(array("\\\\","\\\""), array("&#92;","&#34;"), $json);
    $parts = preg_split("@(\"[^\"]*\")|([\[\]\{\},:])|\s@is", $json, - 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ( $parts as $index => $part ) {
        if (strlen($part) == 1) {
            switch ($part) {
                case "[" :
                case "{" :
                    $parts[$index] = "array(";
                    break;
                case "]" :
                case "}" :
                    $parts[$index] = ")";
                    break;
                case ":" :
                    $parts[$index] = "=>";
                    break;
                case "," :
                    break;
                default :
                    return null;
            }
        } else {
            if ((substr($part, 0, 1) != "\"") || (substr($part, - 1, 1) != "\"")) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    $json = str_replace(array("&#92;","&#34;","$"), array("\\\\","\\\"","\\$"), implode("", $parts));
    return eval("return $json;");
}
```

Comment: Uhhh... This won't work... `\s` is for spaces and if you strip the backslash the regex is not the same. Why do people upvote this?

Comment: @nalply the json was not properly escaped  and would return `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` in the first place .. good observation .. correcting it now

Comment: thanks for the function, but please see my edit above. thank you.

Comment: Ok .. writing as fast as i can .. hold on

Comment: Why eval("return $json;") - this opens the door for hackers.

Comment: @nalply .. yeah .. but its minimal ... the string would always start with `return array("......`  but would try to improve it

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$config = '{"regex": "/font-size:\\\\s*(?:.*);/i"}';
```

Note the quadruple backslash.

**Rationale:** Even in single quoted string the backslash has the escaping function. With `'\''` you have a string `'` (SINGLE QUOTE ONLY). Therefore you also need to escape the backslash. `'\\'` is the string `\` (BACKSLASH ONLY).

But why quadruple the backslash?

When assigning the variable `$config`, then you lose two backslashes. They are "used" up.

Then, JSON itself needs the remaining two backslashes.

Execution log:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"regex": "/font-size:\\\\s*(?:.*);/i"}'));

class stdClass#2 (1) {
  public $regex =>
  string(23) "/font-size:\\s*(?:.*);/i"
}
```

Did you see the double backslash in the JSON output? They have to stay, or the JSON would be invalid.

Comment: It's more complicated. You need to quadruple escape that damned backslash, then it's working.

Comment: `quadruple escape` does the trick! thanks. but it is tedious work to do - how can I write a function to make `\` into a `\\\\`? is it possible?

Comment: This is a different question. :-)